# React store management

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I am creating a react app, in my components I have some root component that renders all sub-components which handles the state on their own.

I have some cases, where some siblings components need to get data from other component, My initial instinct is to use the root component to negotiate, but then the root component may be huge/monolith component.

Is there some way to improve this? or do I need to use the flux architecture?

Comment: The root component communicator is the best approach without flux. If you think it's getting bloated add Redux or MobX or whatever state management thing you like best.

Comment: @azium `the best approach` is a bold statement :) He could also implement simple `Store` where child components publish/subscribe for data without knowledge of the root component. It would be even more efficient since re-render could be done for particular child instead whole app tree.

Comment: @mklimek I politely disagree with you here. @ azium is correct, the best approach would be a centralized single store in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the Flux architecture and the libraries that implement variants such as Redux but it does make this type of communication much simpler. In your case the root component to talk to siblings will be the Parent(root) component.

Here are some strategies for component communication:

**Parent to Child:** Props and Ref Functions

**Child to Parent:** Callback Functions and Event Bubbling

**Sibling to Sibling:** Parent Component

**Any to Any:** Observer Pattern, Global Variables, Context

Here is a good article explaining the different strategies: [React Component Communication](http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/)